# How to setup 2 express servers with same domain

Tags: express, nginx

I have a domain: dev.example.com.

If a user goes to dev.example.com/service/api/ I want to call an express server.

If a user goes to dev.expample.com/lib/ I want to call another express server.

When I set up the different location's in my sites-enabled/default Nginx only will contact /service/api even when I specifiy in the URL I'm looking for /lib/.

How do I fix this?

Comment: why you don't use routing?

Answer (score 0):

You could try adding this to your `nginx.conf`:

```
upstream express_server_1 {
  server ip:port;
}

upstream express server_2 {
  server ip:port;
}

server {
  listen 80;
  listen 443; # if https available

  server_name dev.example.com

  location /service/api {
    proxy_set_header X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
    proxy_set_header Host $server_name;
    proxy_pass http://express_server_1; #https://express_server_1 if https available
  }

   location /lib {
     proxy_set_header X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
     proxy_set_header Host $server_name;
     proxy_pass http://express_server_2;
   }
}
```

This could work if you are really running two servers and need to proxy-pass to them. I can't give you a more precise answer in regards to (not) stripping the prefix paths etc. since your question is really vague and no configs are attached.